# Mostrar dos decimales js array

Tags: javascript, array

estoy haciendo un cálculo con javascript el cual me funciona bien con la siguiente función, pero quiero que me arroje solo dos decimales, he intentado con .toFixed(2) pero no logro que resulte.

```
function calcular(){
    cal = document.getElementsByName("calibre[]");
    tot = document.getElementsByName("total[]");
    for(var x = 0; x < cal.length; x++){ 
        tot[x].value = (cal[x].value * 100)/120;                    
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponiendo tienes un array de tus números digitados y el total será igualmente un `array` puedes hacer un push al array total para ir insertando los valores y agregando el método `.toFixed()` para redondear los valores, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let numeros = [4,5,6,7];
let total = [];

for(let x = 0; x < numeros.length; x++){

  console.log(numeros[x]);
    
   total.push(numeros[x] * 100 / 120);
   
   console.log(total[x].toFixed(2));
  
  
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, esto era lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: Para servirte compañero :)

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba, la funcion .toFixed() funciona prueba a imprimir tot[x].value.toFixed(2)

```js
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2)
document.write(n)
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado pero la consola me arroja: Uncaught TypeError: tot[x].value.toFixed is not a function

Comment: @ddiaz haz un console.log(tot[x]) y lo añades a la pregunta a ver que es lo que pinta, y pon la funcion completa como snippet como yo para que pueda probar

Comment: Podrias indicar los valores que recibe **cal** y **tot**???

Comment: @Kamousagi el valor de **cal** es digitado en varios input y al perder el foco debe entregar el resultado en los input **tot** correspondientes, segun la formula del codigo

Comment: @ddiaz el error que obtienes es debido a que `tot[x].value` es de tipo `string`, usa `parseFloat`, es decir `parseFloat(tot[x].value).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score -2):

Puedes usar esto toFixed():

```
var twoValueFloat = parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2)
```